# Qt toolbar mouse events

Tags: qt, user-interface

In a Qt 5.7 application, QActions on a QToolbar only call their _triggered() slot/callback when the mouse is pressed ***and released*** while over that toolbar icon.

How do I configure QAction so that the _triggered() event occurs as soon as the mousedown event occurs over the icon, without waiting for mouse-up?

Comment: You could try installing a suitable [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) on either the `QToolBar` itself (using `QToolBar::actionAt` to associate a mouse button press with a particular action) or on the `QWidget` returned by [`QToolBar::widgetForAction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#widgetForAction).

Comment: I agree with G. M. You'll also probably want to avoid triggering on mouse release so it doesn't trigger twice, so your event filter will need to "eat" the mouse release event.